# Rails 3 HasMany Through with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through, single-table-inheritance

Here is my STI Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Athlete < User
  has_many :sports, :through => :user_sports
  has_many :user_sports
end

class Coach < User
end
```

The `UserSports` table has `user_id` and `sport_id`... but then you run this:

```
athlete = Athlete.all.last
athlete.sports
```

The SQL that is generated is trying to use the `athlete_id` instead of the `user_id`... not too sure what I am doing wrong here... any suggestions would be greatful!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have a UserSports table. You can just use a foreign key for either User or Sport, depending on their relation to each other.

The User model would need a specified relation to the Sport model, and vice versa.

More information on that is here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association

It makes sense that it's trying to pull the athlete_id instead of the user_id, since you are calling on an Athlete object.

As a side note: There is no need to write `Athlete.all.last` - you only need to write `Athlete.last`.